# Jpeg images resolution is not properly set by Wand

Tags: python, wand

I'm trying to resize a jpeg image and to enlarge the frame. To do this I apply a resize to original image and I compose it on a newer image:

```py
with Image(blob=binary_data) as img:
    ...
    img.resize(width=new_width, height=long(2000))
    # Compose image to enlarge frame
    with Image(width=1571, height=2000, background=Color('white')) as dst_image:
        ...
        dst_image.composite(img, x, 0)
        img = dst_image
        img.resolution = (300,300)
        img.format = 'jpg'
        jpeg_bin = img.make_blob()
```

At the end I would expect a resolution of 300dpi. Imagemagick command
"identify" shows a resolution of 300dpi but it's not true; indeed if I open it
with Gimp it shows a resolution of 72dpi.

I'm using Wand v.0.4.4.

Is my code wrong? ... Any ideas?

Comment: Try EXIFTOOL to see what the actual density/resolution is. You may also have to specify a set of units such as pixelsperinch via wand. If not specified, some tools do not know how to interpret the density/resolution. See wand.image.UNIT_TYPES

Comment: Thank you @fmw42 it works, it put details about fix in answer below.

Answer (score 1):

@fmw42: Thank you, it was a matter of units definition. Before the fix this was the output of exiftools:

```
  Resolution Unit                 : None
  X Resolution                    : 300
  Y Resolution                    : 300
```

I fixed it inserting this line:

```
  dst_image.units = 'pixelsperinch'
```

Now exiftools and gimp returns the same resolution:

```
  Resolution Unit                 : inches
  X Resolution                    : 300
  Y Resolution                    : 300
```

Thank you!